# iPhone SDK AVAudioRecorder delay before recording

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, delay, avaudiorecorder

I'm using the AVAudioRecorder to grab audio from the microphone. The problem i'm facing is this: the first time I start recording there is a 2 second delay between when I tell the recorder to start and when it actually starts. Subsequent recording calls execute much quicker.  Are there any obvious bugs here? What can I do to speed up time it takes to start the initial recording.

I initialized the recorder in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *fileName = @"test.aiff";
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *soundFile = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];
}
```

Then when I'm ready i start the recorder by calling my startRecoring method:

```
-(void) startRecording{
    NSLog(@"Trying to start Recording");
    [audioRecorder record];
    NSLog(@"Recording started");
}
```

Here is the Log output and you can see that there is roughly 2.5 seconds between the two NSLog calls. On the first time clicked but not other times:

```
First recorder call    
2011-04-13 15:41:47.495 AudioRecorderTest[6570:207] Trying to start Recording
2011-04-13 15:41:49.869 AudioRecorderTest[6570:207] Recording started

Next Recorder Call
2011-04-13 15:42:49.236 AudioRecorderTest[6570:207] Trying to start Recording
2011-04-13 15:42:49.246 AudioRecorderTest[6570:207] Recording started
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Creates an audio file at the location
>   specified by the url parameter in the
>   initWithURL:settings:error: method. If
>   a file already exists at that
>   location, this method overwrites it.
>
> The preparation invoked by this method
>   takes place automatically when you
>   call record. Use prepareToRecord when
>   you want recording to start as quickly
>   as possible upon calling record.

try calling [prepareToRecord](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008238-CH1-SW2) after initializing the audio recorder

Answer (score 0):

After initializing the recorder, in addition to prepareToRecord, try inserting:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;

[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
if(err) {
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
if(err){
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```